# Firefox dotted border misplacement

Tags: css, firefox

I have a table with `border-collapse` and most cells with `dotted` border.

The rendering in Firefox is odd.

The code is:

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid blue">a</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid blue">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px dotted blue">a</td>
    <td style="border: 1px dotted blue">b</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

This is how it renders in Chrome vs Firefox:

[image: Table with border collapse and dotted border]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I just tried this snippet in Firefox 57 and this is rendering fine for me. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in `browsers in rendering one pixel wide dotted borders`, but there's no workaround for `border of size 1px` .In this particular case, the bug seems to disappear if you  `set the border width to 2px` or more.

```css
table td{
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 2px solid blue">a</td>
    <td style="border: 2px solid blue">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border: 2px dotted blue">a</td>
    <td style="border: 2px dotted blue">b</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use CSS Outlines.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

**However, keep in mind that outlines are unlike borders:**

> Outlines never take up space, as they are drawn outside of an element's content.

So in that case with border collapse your outlines would run over each other on your table cells.  This can fixed by adding a -1px `outline-offset`.

Two examples are below, First table using outline, and the second table using border for comparison.

**Obligatory Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/sh9oqq2k/1/

**Browser support:**

https://caniuse.com/#search=outline

```css
/* global */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 8px;
}

/* outline */
tr:nth-child(1) td {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td {
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

/* border */
table.bordered tr:nth-child(1) td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
table.bordered tr:nth-child(2) td {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Outline
</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>
  Border
</p>
<table class='bordered'>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```